# libplist version issue(checking for libplist-2.0 >= 2.3.0... no)

Tags: libimobiledevice

checking for libplist-2.0 >= 2.3.0... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libplist-2.0 >= 2.3.0) were not met:

Package 'libplist-2.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libplist_CFLAGS
and libplist_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

why it is giving error? I am using it in msys2 env (windows)